# Observable with initial value

Tags: angular

Using observable, I want to filter and display a list. The input `event` is fired only when the user starts typing. Therefore the list is not displayed at the first place. How can I assign a default value to the observable `this.filterLocation$` until the `inputEvent` starts to be triggered?

template

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-location [ngForOf]="filterLocation$ | async">
        <a mat-list-item href="#">{{location}}</a>
      </ng-template>
```

component

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
const searchBox = document.querySelector('#search-input');
this.filterLocation$ = fromEvent(searchBox, 'input')
  .pipe(
    map((e: any) => {
      const value = e.target.value;
        return value ? this.locations
          .filter(l => l.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
          : this.locations;
      }),
      startWith(this.locations)
  )
 }
}
```

Using `startWith` makes the list to be displayed initially. But the following error is thrown:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngForOf: null'. Current value: 'ngForOf: name1,name2'.

[live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wur3y3)

Comment: As it was stated in deleted answer, it's preferable to use DOM by means of Angular, i.e. reactive forms in this case. Form control naturally provides an observable.

Comment: @estus I edited the question providing the live code. Even If I do use a formControl on the input element, the same issue would happen. Because the `valueChanges` observable will be return after the first change whereas I would like to have an initial value before the first change on the observable.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't affect current problem. Just a note. I had similar issues with form controls, too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Initial value can be provided to an observable with `startWith` operator, as it was already mentioned in now-deleted answer.

The problem is that `filterLocation$` is assigned too late, after `filterLocation$ | async` was evaluated to `null`. Since the change occurs on same tick, this results in change detection error (though `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` can be considered a warning if its occurrence is expected).

The solution is to move the code from `ngAfterViewInit` to `ngOnInit`, before change detection was triggered.

This is not always possible. An alternative is to provide a value asynchronously, so it doesn't interfere with initial change detection.

By delaying the whole observable with `delay` operator (acceptable solution for user input because it's not time critical):

```
  this.filterLocation$ = fromEvent(searchBox, 'input')
  .pipe(
    map((e: any) => { 
      const value = e.target.value;
        return value ? this.locations
          .filter(l => l.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
          : this.locations;
    }),
    startWith(this.locations),
    delay(0)
  )
```

Or by making initial value asynchronous with a scheduler:

```
import { asyncScheduler } from 'rxjs'
...

  this.filterLocation$ = fromEvent(searchBox, 'input')
  .pipe(
    map((e: any) => { 
      const value = e.target.value;
        return value ? this.locations
          .filter(l => l.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
          : this.locations;
    }),
    startWith(this.locations, asyncScheduler)
  )
```

Comment: Great answer! The delay operator was what I was missing. But thanks for pointing out also the use of the async scheduler. But I think, it is  `asyncScheduler` instead of  `Scheduler.async`

Comment: Both asyncScheduler  and Scheduler.async work. asyncScheduler  was introduced in RxJS 6 and isn't documented yet, i'm not sure about it's status. While Scheduler.async is established and documented since 4.